# How to add coefficients to existing data base such that their effect on the final intercept is given?

Tags: r, dataframe, coefficients

Firstly, let's say I have a data frame `df` with variables `y, x1, x2`, `x1` is a continuous variable and `x2` is a factor.

Let's say I have a model:

```
model <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df, family = binomial)
```

This will result in an object where I can extract the coefficients using the command `model$coefficients`.

However, for use in another program I would like to export the data frame `df`, but I'd also like to be able to display the results of the model beyond simply adding the fitted values to the data frame.

Therefore I would like to have `coeff1*x1` and `coeff2*x2` also in the same dataframe, so that I could use these **and** the original data together to display their effects. The problem arises from the fact that one of the variables is a multi-level factor and therefore it's not preferable to simply use a for-loop to extract the coefficients and multiply the variables with them.

Is there another way to add two **new** variables to the dataframe `df` such that they've been derived from combining the original variables `x1, x2` and their respective coefficients?

Comment: Which data frame?  `glm` returns an object which is a (subclass) of `glm`.  I don't see how adding coefficients to the *input* data frame (`df`) makes sense.  Exactly *what* do you want to add?  The strings you list, or the coefficients of the corresponding terms?  (When you add them to which model?)  As it stands, I can make no sense of your question.  Please provide a detailed example of your expected output.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: Is this more comperehensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 10

df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(N, 10, 1),
                 x2 = sample(1:3, N, TRUE), 
                 y = as.integer(50 - x2* 0.4 + x1 * 1.2 + rnorm(N, 0, 0.5) > 52))

model <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df, family = binomial)

# add column for intercept
df <- cbind(x0 = rep(1, N), df)
df$intercept <- df$x0 * model$coefficients["(Intercept)"]
df[["coeff1*x1"]] <- df$x1 * model$coefficients["x1"]
df[["coeff2*x2"]] <- df$x2 * model$coefficients["x2"]

# x0        x1 x2 y intercept     coeff1*x1     coeff2*x2
# 1   1  9.439524  1 1  24.56607 -3.361333e-06 -4.281056e-07
# 2   1  9.769823  1 1  24.56607 -3.478949e-06 -4.281056e-07
# 3   1 11.558708  1 1  24.56607 -4.115956e-06 -4.281056e-07
```

Alternatively:

```
# add column for intercept
df <- cbind(x0 = rep(1, N), df)
tmp <- as.data.frame(Map(function(x, y) x * y, subset(df, select = -y),     model$coefficients))
names(tmp) <- paste0("coeff*", names(model$coefficients))
cbind(df, tmp)
```

Comment: It's a good solution, however there is but one problem:
If I were to use this then let's say `x2` has three levels. Then I have extra dummy variables `x21, x22, x23` and if used `model$coefficients["x2"]`, it would return `NA`.